# Outlook Add in: Get selected event id from Outlook Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

[image]I'm creating an Outlook add-in and i'd like to know how to get selected appointment
( event ) id from outlook calendar. I want to display the selected calendar appointment ( event ) data in outlook calendar Add Ins.

Comment: To clarify, are you writing a web add-in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview)? If so there is currently no extension point in the calendar view. Could you provide more information on the scenario or screenshot on where you'd like your addin to run?

Comment: I have used msgraph-sdk-javascript to import the event in Outlook Calendar. But i want to get the selected appointment (event ) id or data of the appointment.  I have to display the selected appointment (event) data in calendar Add ins.

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood that about where you want to run the addin. Now I understood that you want the addin to run on the calendar item that is opened. It looks like you have made another post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157819/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-access-the-selected-appointment-event-in-ou Let's stop here and use the other post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to programmatically access the selected appointment (event) in outlook using Office Add In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157819/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-access-the-selected-appointment-event-in-ou)