# Is it possible to programmatically access the selected appointment (event) in outlook using Office Add In

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

How to get the selected appointment data from outlook calendar Add Ins. I have added the Add Ins in Outlook calendar. I want to get the selected appointment ( event ) data. Because i need to display the selected event in Outlook Add Ins. Is this possible ? [image]( using javascript )

Answer (score 0):

You can use Office.js APIs to get the details of current item or mailbox.
For selected item's data you can use [Office.context.mailbox.item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#officecontextmailboxitem) APIs.
Please check the API reference [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview) for complete API set.

Comment: Ya, i can get the selected appointment data using Office.context.mailbox.item when i open the appointment. But in edit calendar Outlook Add Ins, Office.context.mailbox.item is not returning the open event data. How to get the edit appointment data in Outlook calendar Add Ins . Is this possible to get ?.

Comment: For "Office.context.mailbox.item" to work on a item, it must have been saved once. 
It won't return itemId for a new compose/appointment until its saved.

Comment: Got it, But if someone accept my invitation and i got email response that someone has accepted your invitation. So when i read that email message and open my add in with three dot menu (i.e from MessageReadSurface) then  i get different itemId.

How can i  get any unique and same  id there also which was i am getting in saved event.